# Meteor {{#markdown}}

Tags: html, css, meteor, markdown, meteor-blaze

I am making a forum with markdown support.

I've been using meteor's markdown parser `{{#markdown}}` and have found something disturbing that I can't seem to figure out.

I am using `{{#markdown}}{{content}}{{/markdown}}` to render the content inserted into database.

The disturbing thing, for example, if someone writes up html without inserting it into the code block in the content...

#### example

```
<div class = "col-md-12">
    Content Here
</div>
```

This will render as a column. They could also make buttons and etc through writing the HTML for it.

How to disable this behaviour so that when HTML is written it will not render into HTML but just simply show it as text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write global helper, which will strip all html tags:

```
function stripHTML(string){
      s = string.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '');
      return s;
}
Template.registerHelper('stripHTML', stripHTML)
```

Usage :

```
{{#markdown}}{{stripHTML content}}{{/markdown}}
```

Test it in console:

```
stripHTML("<div>Inside dive</div> Text outside")
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have tried this but if I do this, I get nothing within the markdown helpers..

Comment: `multiArgs(args, function(tag) { ` It says there is an error here

Comment: one sec... yeah you are right. multiargs is function inside sugar.js, which is not included. ok, I will simplify this example.

Comment: Thank you for your dedicated contribution. I guess now I will learn regex to just replace < > with &lt; &rt; when its a html entity (sanitizing html)